# Find the expected payoff for different strategies

Tags: regression

I have recorded on a continuous scale (between 0 and 15) the strategy some players used in a video game and their associate payoff (also interval-ratio) in this game, so I have lots of couples of values like (2.34,12), etc.

I would now like to have an idea of what strategy brings the highest payoff in the game, or what would be the expected payoff for each strategy. It is difficult to see a clear relationship between strategy and payoff on a visual inspection. A 2D scatter plot gives this:

[image]

but there are lots of points stacked up on this plot. A 3D histogram gives a better idea of the distribution:

[image]

So I tried to do a loess regression on this data. Here is the smooth curve computed by loess:

[image]

but the R² of this regression is very low, 0.09.

Do you see a regression that would be best suited for this kind of data or should I stick with Loess regression?

Comment: This sounds like a game theory problem.

Comment: I imagine there are more variables involved than strategy that affect the payoff.

Comment: @Glen_b For now I only have the strategy as variable

Answer (score 0):

Since strategy is continuous, you might start by considering a smooth regression relationship between payoff and strategy, perhaps something like a [loess curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression).

However, you might wish to consider whether leaving out an important predictor could mislead you. Firstly, it can make relationships much noisier than they would otherwise be, and secondly, it can bias your estimates of the relationships with the [variables you do have, even changing their sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)

Comment: I've edited my post with data distribution and results from Loess regression. Do you still think it's the most adapted regression?

Comment: Now I see your data, a single curve - of any kind - is not remotely suitable; there's a clear suggestion of an important, missing variable, making the marginal relationship uninterpretable. What do you mean "most adapted regression"?

Comment: I mean either try to fit the data to a predefined non-linear function, or use another type of smoothing like smoothing spline? Also, I have no idea as to what "span" smoothness parameter use for my loess smoothing. thanks

Comment: Actually there is no missing variable in this specific dataset. It's just that if players play strategy "6" for example, they have half a chance to win 9, and half a chance to win 0. that's how I got this kind of distribution. Now is it possible to have an idea from this data what strategy brings the highest payoff on average?

Comment: Yes so to make it more clear I'm not trying to get the best fit, I just want to have an idea from my data of what strategy brings the highest payoff on average.

Comment: if something has two possible outcomes with known probability for each, you can calculate (rather than estimate) the conditional mean at each value of strategy. Just find the exact conditional mean as a function of strategy and optimize that.

Comment: I don't know the exact probabilities of each outcome unfortunately... Thus my need to estimate the conditional payoffs from the data. So a loess smoothing curve is not suitable for estimating this?

Comment: One of the problems with it being really suitable is that it ignores what it sees as "outliers", which is usually fine, but you really don't want it to do here. Another is that the loess curve doesn't account for the known variance structure of a binomial outcome, for example. It might do okay with some tweaking; a modified weighted local regression might do okay, but you're probably better seeing if this can be transformed into a binomial glm (by rescaling the known endpoints to 0-1), fitting a smooth function, and then transforming back.